# Getimagesize is not working in host server - Hostinger

Tags: php, getimagesize

Code:

```
$urli = 'https://st.quantrimang.com/photos/image/2020/02/20/Zalo-bat-tim-quanh-day-1.jpg';
$size = getimagesize($urli);
echo $urli.'.</br>Size:';
echo $size[0].'</br>';
```

If run in localhost => `$size[0]` ok - Run in server hostinger => `$size[0]` NULL 
Ps: `allow_url_fopen is ON` (check by: `phpinfo();` Tks help@

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the directory.
The

```
'https://st.quantrimang.com/photos/image/2020/02/20/Zalo-bat-tim-quanh-day-1.jpg';
```

is the path for the HTML Wrapper. But PHP looks in the physical directory of the server (similar to your C:/xampp/htdocs/my_projects/st.quantrimang.com/photos ... on your Home-PC) On localhost both are (normally) the same.
On live server the structure of the directory is more complex, because every customer has its own sub-directory. In the path to your physical directory on the live server are your accountnumber (and other things) also included.
In short words: use

```
$my_server_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // could be a very long path
```

to get the server-root of your domain. Then

```
$urli = $my_server_directory.'/my_image_directory/image.jpg';
$size = getimagesize($urli);
```

should work.

Btw: 'allow_url_fopen' is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Tks need2know answered. File getimagesize.php have code and run. URL image in web, file php run get to imagesize => not chage url image.